# Create a link to Google Maps that will populate with markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page that lists a series of locations, essentially a road trip with predefined stops, and all the locations are marked on a Google Maps map on the page. So I've already created Google Maps markers with locations/coordinates.

Is there a way to send these locations via a link or something to open in Google Maps? Allowing Google to handle all the directions and so forth.

**EDIT:** I'm not sure how to clear this up but I'll try

**I have on my page:**

- A Google Maps instance
- It has markers on it to mark locations provided by the page

**What I need:**
A way to send this marker information to Google Maps. Potentially through a URL or something but I'm not sure.

My team feels it makes more sense for Google Maps to handle all the directions features and prints features and save features etc.

Comment: what have you created exactly?

Comment: @Vishwanath A Google Maps instance, with markers plotted on it. I would like to send this info to Google Maps so they can directly handle stuff like directions, printing directions, send directions/markers to your phone and saving those locations.

Comment: I think you will need to intgegrate google maps directions yourself. Not sure if you can get what you want.

Comment: A suggestion for how to make the questions more clear would be useful? I'm not sure how I can make it better.

Comment: This question probably alreasy have answer on webapps.se . http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/12475/how-do-i-plot-a-bunch-of-points-on-google-maps All you will have to do is generate kml file or look for other solutions there.

Comment: You could probably use the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-simple) for this. Populate your start and end points using your marker locations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Working as of August 2015*

**Google Maps /dir/ URL**
Using the following format you can generate a link to Google Maps containing a string of forward slash delimited coordinates.

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/51.0872877,-115.3715704/51.1627618,-115.5600419/53.5451428,-113.4850327/

Very basic implementation example:

```
var GMapsDirURL = "https://www.google.com/maps/dir/"
var GMapsURLMarkers = "";

for (){
 // Your for loop where creating Markers
 GMapsURLMarkers += Marker.coordinates + "/";
}

GMapsDirURL += GMapsURLMarkers;
```

Append your final GMapsDirURL to an href and you've got a link to Google maps with directions between all points.